# Sending touches began to parent view not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have overridden touches began in a sub view controller and I am sending them to the root view controller like so:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    println("touchesBegan CardItemController")
    var root = self.navController?.viewControllers[0] as! MainViewController
    root.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}
```

I have checked to see if touchesBegan is being called in the parent view controller like so:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    println("touchesBegan MainViewController")
}
```

which it is being called but in another subview of the root view controller the touchesBegan isn't being called... in the root I have the CardItemController as a subview as well as another subview which is added first.

I've tried sending the touches began to the subview of the root view controller like so:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    println("touchesBegan MainViewController")
    mainView.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}
```

but this just seems to create a never ending loop and crashes the app. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You should _never_ call `touchesBegan` (as you are doing with `root.touchesBegan()`. What is the _real_ goal here? You need to rearchitect your entire approach.

Comment: I want touch events to be sent to a subview in the root view controller from a sibling subview in the root view controller.

Comment: No, you can't mean that, since a view controller is not a "subview". Please go up to a higher level of conception. Do not speak of touch events. Pretend you had never heard of them. Just describe _conceptually_ what you are trying to do.

Comment: Only been programming iOS for a month so sorry I'm not sure about terminology. So I have a pageviewcontroller where I need touch events on the entire screen but the first page only takes up part of the screen and the others take up the entire screen. The first page is like a card and needs to be swiped through but the background should stand still. This background has buttons on it and i'm trying to get the buttons to work but am having trouble since this pageviewcontroller sits on top of it.

Comment: Are these buttons part of the page view controller's view, or are they behind the _entire_ page view controller? If the latter, you are using the page view controller wrong. There should be _nothing_ behind it. Are you sure you even put the page view controller legally into the interface in the first place?

Comment: Yeh its the latter the buttons are behind the entire page view controller. I put the pageviewcontroller in the interface like this view.addSubview(pageViewController!.view) if I add the buttons using pageviewcontroller.view.addSubview then the pageviewcontroller no longer get any touch events.

Comment: Right, but you do know that when you put a page view controller's view into your interface like that, you have to do some other stuff to make it your own child view controller? - Okay, but let's get back to the original design. Would it be so bad if those buttons were inside the first "page" instead of behind the whole page view controller? That would easily solve the touches problem.

Comment: yeh thats how I have it right now but won't work because it slides the background and all the buttons on each screen we need those to stay stationary. As for the pageviewcontroller I have it set up as a child using addChildViewController(pageViewController!)